# Product of concave functions is concave

Tags: functions, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I have something like this $$ h(x) = f(x) g(x) $$ where $f$ and $g$ are some nice functions such that $f$ is $[0,1]$-bounded, concave function and $g$ is some negative, decreasing, concave function.

Is $h$ concave? If not, then can we impose more conditions on $f$ and $g$ such that $h$ is concave?

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are concave then log($f$) and log($g$) are concave, and their sum is concave, so log($h$) is concave. Is it enough for log($h$) to be concave? Jus' sayin' . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $f$ be **decreasing** concave and bounded and $g(x)=-x$. Then $fg$ is actually convex for $x >0$. You can see this by computing the second derivative.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take 
$$
f(x)=g(x)=x,
$$
which is concave (but not *strictly* concave).

Then $h(x)=x^2$, which is convex.

NB I take the definition of concavity from Wikipedia. It might be the other way round in your textbook.

You can then easily find strictly concave examples. Take
$$
f(x)=g(x)=x^{2/3},
$$
which are both concave, but $f\times g$ is clearly convex.